# Can pgadmin and pgmodeler connect to Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin, erd, google-cloud-spanner

I want to start cloud spanner emulator in docker, and then use pgadmin to connect to emulator, but when creating server, I am not sure how to fill in the username and maintenance, has anyone tried it? Because I think cloud spanner is also using pgsql, so I should be able to connect to emulator with pgadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner itself does not support the PostgreSQL wire protocol, which means that you cannot connect directly to Cloud Spanner using `psql` or any other PostgreSQL tool. There is however an open source adapter that will allow you to use `psql` with Cloud Spanner. The adapter can be found here: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/pgadapter

I don't think that `pgAdmin` will work with the adapter, as `pgAdmin` will also automatically execute a number of queries on the system tables of `PostgreSQL` to determine which tables etc. are in the database. Those queries will probably fail.

An alternative to using `pgAdmin` could be to use `DBeaver`: https://dbeaver.io/.

`DBeaver` has built-in support for Google Cloud Spanner.

When creating a connection to Cloud Spanner in `DBeaver`, make sure to select the `Google Cloud Spanner JDBC Driver` and not the `Google Cloud Spanner Community (Topicus) Driver`. The latter is deprecated and does not support the newest features of Cloud Spanner.

The following screenshot shows the connection dialog for Google Cloud Spanner in DBeaver Community Edition 7.3.0.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so, can DBeaver community be used to connect to cloud spanner?

Comment: Can navicat connect to cloud spanner, if so I'll use navicat. DBeaver has been unsuccessful in cracking it.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Navicat, so I can't say whether that works or not. DBeaver certainly does work. See the screenshot that I just added above.